# VisualStudio generated DataSet Exceptions

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Is there anyway to determine the Exceptions that can be thrown by methods in a DataSet that has been generated by VisualStudio (using the Data > Add New Data Source menu option) other than look through the generated code?

Comment: I don't think so. Why do you need to know?

Comment: Primarily for more detailed error reporting and possibly for better exception handling. Simply catching Exception works but could be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like [Exception Hunter](http://www.red-gate.com/products/Exception_Hunter/index.htm) to track them all down. (I haven't tried it myself, but I've used other Red Gate products and they are quality.)